# Polars Conditional Replacement From Another DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have two DataFrames like this.

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({
  "col_1": np.random.rand(),
  "col_2": np.random.rand(),
  "col_3": np.random.rand()
})
```

```
┌──────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ col_1    ┆ col_2   ┆ col_3    │
│ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64     ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 0.526435 │
└──────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

```
df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    "col_1": np.random.randint(0, 2, 5),
    "col_2": np.random.randint(0, 2, 5),
    "col_3": np.random.randint(0, 2, 5)
})
```

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col_1 ┆ col_2 ┆ col_3 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     │
│ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 0     │
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 0     │
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

I want to replace the 1s in the second DataFrame with the corresponding value in the 2nd DataFrame. And the zeros should be replaced with 1s. Resulting in this:

```
┌──────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ col_1    ┆ col_2   ┆ col_3    │
│ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64     ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ 1.0      ┆ 1.0     ┆ 1.0      │
│ 1.0      ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 1.0      │
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 0.526435 │
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 1.0      │
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 0.526435 │
└──────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

I tried reshaping `df1` to have the same height as `df2`, like this:

```
df1 = df1.select(pl.all().repeat_by(df2.height).arr.explode())
```

And if I rename the columns so they're not the same, I could horizontally concatenate the 2 DataFrames using `pl.concat`. But I'm unsure where to go from there. How could I achieve this? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a use-case for [`.map_dict`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html#polars.Expr.map_dict):

```
df2.select(
   pl.col(col).map_dict({0: 1, 1: df1.get_column(col).item()}) 
   for col in df2.columns
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ col_1    ┆ col_2   ┆ col_3    │
│ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64     ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ 1.0      ┆ 1.0     ┆ 1.0      │
│ 1.0      ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 1.0      │
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 0.526435 │
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 1.0      │
│ 0.534349 ┆ 0.84115 ┆ 0.526435 │
└──────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

The previous approach was to add a suffix and use [`.with_context`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.with_context.html#polars.LazyFrame.with_context)

```
(df2
 .lazy()
 .with_context(
    df1.lazy().with_columns(pl.all().suffix("_right")))
 .select(
    pl.when(pl.col(col) == 1)
      .then(pl.col(f"{col}_right"))
      .otherwise(1)
      .alias(col)
    for col in df2.columns)
).collect()
```

Comment: I did not know about `get_column`. Very clean solution